# Cast an object to class type passed as parameter

Tags: java, class, generics

I have a parent class and 2 child classes. I am trying to implement a function that takes the type of the child and which child as parameters.

When I use `child.newInstance()`, I want to store it in a variable of the type that is passed and call a function from the second parameter.

Below are the classes

```
public class Parent {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test from parent");
    }
}

public class ChildA extends Parent {
    public void testChildA() {
        System.out.println("Test from child a");
    }
}

public class ChildB extends Parent {
    public void testChildB() {
        System.out.println("Test from child b");
    }
}
```

and here is the method I'm trying to implement

```
public class Driver {
    Parent func(Class child, String whichChild) throws Exception {
        // whichChild: "ChildA" or "ChildB"

        Object obj = child.newInstance();
        // cast obj to type of child and call the method "test" and "test" + whichChild
    }
}
```

Can it be done what I am trying to do? If yes, how can I cast this object to the type that is passed?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this ? and why don't you just override test in the children?

Comment: I can't change the structure of the classes and I can't override the methods, because the child methods do other functionality, I added the `super.test();` by mistake, sorry about that

Comment: Compile-time safety and static analysis are very powerful and useful tools, when using reflection API you loose all benefits they provide. You will not know whether the code works until you run it. It will not be possible to find usages of the methods you call via reflection. Also IDE will be reporting that methods are unused, which won't be true. See Andy Turner's answer what's the best way to do something like this.

Comment: @aizen92 can you add extra abstract method in `Parent` class?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak No I can't add anything the `Parent` class

Comment: @aizen92 I think you are focusing on a wrong thing - you are trying to fix a problem, but you should fix its cause instead. Can you provide more context about what these classes really are? Why can't you modify `Parent`? How are the `Child` classes used? What do they represent?

Comment: @aizen92 if `Parent` is declared as you have stated, i.e. class is not `final`, and with `test` not declared `final`, there is nothing stopping you overriding `test`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Basically `Parent` class has 2 private fields with getters and setters which represent an error code and an error text, and child classes that extend it can have other private fields with getters and setters that can be extra data. They are used for responses from functions if they were successful or not, so for example if I want a child with suspect parameter that gave an issue,  I would need to extend the `Parent` class and add a variable to hold the suspicious variable

Comment: @aizen92 It sound's like perfect place for inheritance. Why can't you modify `Parent` class?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak My functions should always have a code and error text, so I only added those to the `Parent` class, any other data needed are specific to certain functions which is why there are children classes with the extra data needed.

Comment: @aizen92 "I only added those to the `Parent` class" - good, that means that you can modify it. So now use inheritance instead of reflections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a constraint to `child`, you don't need a cast at all to get a Parent:

```
Parent func(Class<? extends Parent> child, String whichChild) throws Exception {
    // whichChild: "ChildA" or "ChildB"

    Parent obj = child.newInstance();
    //...
}
```

However, you still can't call the `testChildA` etc method, since all you have is an instance of `Parent`. You'd need to use reflection to get the method:

```
Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod().getMethod("test" + whichChild);
method.invoke(obj);
```

It would be better to have a method on the interface of `Parent` which you can invoke, and is overridden in the subclasses.

```
public abstract class Parent {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("Test from parent");
  }

  public abstract void testChild();
}
```

then simply call:

```
obj.testChild();
```

or, as Emanuele Ivaldi points out, just override `test` in `ChildA` and `ChildB` and invoke that directly.

Comment: With reflection I can call the method `testChildA` even if `obj` is `Parent` in `Parent obj = child.newInstance();`?

Comment: Sure - you can *call* it - but it doesn't mean that it is guaranteed to work. `Method` is decoupled from the instance that invoke it on. For instance, you could call `method.invoke("string")` - which will result in a runtime exception. It's up to you to ensure that you only call it in a way that makes sense.

Comment: The alternative would be to check the class of the object and cast it to the correct implementation and call the proper method, it's not flexible,it sucks but it avoids using reflection, did I say it sucks?

Answer (score 21):

Not sure exactly what you're doing but you can use `Class.cast(...)`.

Eg

```
public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type) {
    Object o = type.newInstance();
    T t = type.cast(o);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: `return type.newInstance()` would be simpler.

Comment: Agreed, Im just trying to show the usage of `Class.cast(Object)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
public class Driver {
    Parent func(Class child, String whichChild) throws Exception {
        // whichChild: "ChildA" or "ChildB"

        child.forName(whichChild);

        Object obj = child.newInstance();
        // cast obj to type of child and call the method "test" + whichChild
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother passing `child` as a parameter then? It helps if you highlight what you have actually changed, rather than just saying "try this block of code without explanation".

Comment: I agree with that sir. Will edit my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I doubt it. As far as the compiler concerns, any instance of Class can be sent as parameter.

So, for the compiler, there is no proof that this instance is actually an instance of the type you send along.

Comment: `Class<? extends Parent>` constraints it.